Conditions for an open mapping between spectra
Let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ be a Locally Noether Ring, and $\hat{A} = \varprojlim A/ \mathfrak{m}^{n}$ .Furthermore, let $f : A \to \hat{A}$ be a canonical morphism, and consider the mapping $f^{*} : Spec(\hat{A} ) \to Spec(A)$ between spectra induced from it. What is the necessary and sufficient condition for A to be an open mapping for $f^{*}$?
